# phonegap + jquery mobile: css not working

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a phonegap project in which i'm willing to use jquery mobile.
I have look for some example to start with something already tested and here's my problem.
When I launch the app on my Nexus 5 all the elements appear with no style at all. Maybe it's just a matter of placing the code so here's mine. Hopefully someone can find the issue:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Directory</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Panel responsive page" data-url="panel-responsive-page1">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Panel responsive</h1>
    <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
    <h1>Panel responsive</h1>
    <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the push display mode, the right panel reveal. To make this responsive, you can make the page re-flow at wider widths. This allows both the panel menu and page to be used together when more space is available. This behavior is controlled by CSS media queries. You can create a custom one for a specific breakpoint or use the breakpoint preset by adding the <code>class="ui-responsive-panel"</code> to the page container. We have added this class on this demo page. Note that when using the preset class, we also hide the dismiss layer on wider screens if the panel has the push display mode.</p>
<div data-demo-html="#panel-responsive-page1"></div><!--/demo-html -->
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="../" data-rel="back" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Back</a>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="panel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Accordion</a></li>
     [...]
        <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Transitions</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
<div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" id="add-form">
    <form class="userform">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <label for="name">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini">Save</a></div>
        </div>
      </form>
 </div><!-- /panel -->
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/employeelist.js"></script>
<script src="js/employeedetails.js"></script> 
<script src="js/reportlist.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.uplink.agriturismo.com;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.screen);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you created  the style sheet `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />`? Need to remove/comment the stylesheet. The `style.css` could be overiding the `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` stylesheet.

Comment: it's just for the images. Anyway I've tried to remove it and nothing is happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i stucked with same problem finally found that page was not able to get directory of css.

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Also just remove the first / so it would be css/styles.css for example.

Comment: hmm, I am now getting "illegal characters in path" (after adding the ./ )